# Android app throws NumberFormatException on startup

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm very new to Android development, Android Studio and Gradle, but I need to update an old Android Java app with new build tools (Gradle) and dependencies where necessary. I just got to the point when it compiles again, and now I'm starting it in an emulator (Pixel_3a_API_34_extensionelvel_7...).

When the app starts, it immediately stops (quits).

I found that it is casued by a NumberFormatException where parseInt(string s, int radix) is called with s = "google_app_id", radix = 10 - which is probably wrong.

If I continue, the same error happens for s = "google_api_key", "firebase_database_url", "ga_trackingid" and a bunch of others - seems like the int parsing is called for the id string rather than their values.

Maybe just a package version issue?

Update to the original question: I updated dependencies, source and target SDK's, removed Google Analytics dependency (and replaced that with Firebase Analytics). The updated gradle files are below. Error remains the same.

In the meantime I found that google_app_id "belongs" to the Firebase libraries, and searching through intermediate outputs shows that it is present as a defined constant.

**My build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'
        classpath: 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
        classpath: 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    configurations.configureEach {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        }
    }
}
```

**The app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' version '1.4.2' apply false
    id 'io.sentry.android.gradle' version '4.2.0'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace '<mynamespace>'
    compileSdk 34
    buildFeatures.buildConfig true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<myappid>"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 97
        versionName "2.1.12"
    }

    signingConfigs { ... }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_VERSION", "true"
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DEV_VERSION", "false"
        }

        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                outputFileName = "<myapp>" + "_" + variant.versionName + "_" + variant.buildType.name + "_" + variant.versionCode + ".apk"
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        debug { res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res'] }
        release { res.srcDirs = ['src/release/res'] }
        main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/release/res'] }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.colintmiller:simplenosql:0.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.3.7'
    implementation 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.3.7'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:5.0.4.Final'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.3'

    // Use FireBase services
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display' 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
}
```

**google-services.json**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "<myprojectnumber>",
    "firebase_url": "https://<myappname>.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "<myprojectid>",
    "storage_bucket": "<myappname>.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "<mypackagename>"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "<myclientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "<myapikey>"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "<myclientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

**Exception**

```
NumberFormatException in Integer.class
```

[image]

**Error stack**

```
getIdentifier:261, ResourcesImpl (android.content.res)
getIdentifier:2304, Resources (android.content.res)
getString:1, StringResourceValueReader (com.google.android.gms.common.internal)
fromResource:157, FirebaseOptions (com.google.firebase)
initializeApp:240, FirebaseApp (com.google.firebase)
onCreate:69, FirebaseInitProvider (com.google.firebase.provider)
attachInfo:2619, ContentProvider (android.content)
attachInfo:2589, ContentProvider (android.content)
attachInfo:61, FirebaseInitProvider (com.google.firebase.provider)
installProvider:7765, ActivityThread (android.app)
installContentProviders:7276, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleBindApplication:6983, ActivityThread (android.app)
-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication:-1, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleMessage:2236, ActivityThread$H (android.app)
dispatchMessage:106, Handler (android.os)
loopOnce:205, Looper (android.os)
loop:294, Looper (android.os)
main:8177, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:552, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:971, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

**Observations from the call stack**

fromResource 157, FirebaseOptions (com.google.firebase) is

```
 String applicationId = reader.getString(APP_ID_RESOURCE_NAME);
```

where APP_ID_RESOURCE_NAME = "google_app_id"
is correct.

getString:1, StringResourceValueReader  is

```
int name1 = this.zza.getIdentifier(name, "string", this.zzb);
```

where name is "google_app_id"

getIdentifier:2304, Resources (android.content.res) has a single line impl

```
return mResourcesImpl.getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)
```

name argument is a string, method description says

name – The name of the desired resource.

so it is expecting a string value - which is correct.

getIdentifier:261, ResourcesImpl (android.content.res)

is weird:

```
int getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage) {
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("name is null");
    }
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(name);
```

so it accepts a resource name but tries to parse it (the name itself) as an integer.

Doesn't seem right.

**Debugging Resource File generation**
I found this [article about using the google-services.json file](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file).
It says build creates an xml file here

```
app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml
```

For me it is created in a slightly different location:

```
app/build/generated/res/processDebugGoogleServices/values/values.xml
```

Tried copying the file to the location mentioned in the article, but it made no difference.

**Adding resources manually**
I tried adding the items in the above values.xml to a manually created resource xml file. It was found by the build process, merged, but changed nothing re the error.

Comment: Mind sharing the error stack you get?

Answer (score 0):

That rabbit hole was deep.

The problem was not with library, AGP or Gradle versions but the emulator.
<s>I used an Android emulator that came with Visual Studio and was found by Android Studio.</s>

Once I switched to a physical device or the emulators that can be added in Android Studio, the problem disappeared.

The app works correctly with emulators up to API 30 (Android 11), keeps restarting on the newer ones.

The google_api_id exception may be something temporary as I can continue execution once that exception (and dozens of others) is thrown, may not have anything to do with the actual problem.